# how to use and update panels in ncursesw

Tags: c++, unicode, ncurses

I'm currently coding in C++ in Ubuntu WSL2, using the `<panel.h>` header to create panels in ncursesw, as I need Unicode characters.

I've done a couple tests already, where the results are shown in the table below:
[image]

This is the code and result when creating a window with a WINDOW* and -lncursesw.

Code:

```
#include <panel.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    refresh();

    WINDOW *window {newwin(0, 0, 0, 0)};
    
    box(window, 0, 0);
    mvwaddstr(window, 1, 1, "\U0001F600");
    wrefresh(window);

    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Result:

[image]

This is the code and result when creating a window with a PANEL* and -lncursesw.

Code:

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    PANEL *panel {new_panel(newwin(0, 0, 0, 0))};

    box(panel_window(panel), 0, 0);
    mvwaddstr(panel_window(panel), 1, 1, "\U0001F600");
    // wrefresh(panel_window(panel));
    update_panels();
    doupdate();

    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Result:

[image]

However if I uncomment the wrefresh() line, I get the same desired result when using WINDOW *. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`doupdate`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html#h3-wnoutrefresh_doupdate) doesn't do a `wrefresh` (it's generally used after one more more windows is prepared using `wnoutrefresh`).

Without an explicit `wrefresh`, your program is getting the `wrefresh` done as a side-effect of [`getch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) — which refreshes *stdscr*, but that in turn has only the pending `werase` from [`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr) followed by the [`box`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_border.3x.html) call: it seems you'll get an empty box.

Comment: In my previous post: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475015/ncursesw-causing-weird-behaviour/69486620#69486620>, the example only uses update_panels() and do_update() to show the box layout of the three panels. How does that work and why isn't wrefresh() needed there?

Comment: It doesn't work.  You're drawing boxes on *stdscr* in each case.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly used `-lpanel -lncursesw`, when I should've been using `-lpanelw -lncursesw` instead. That fixed it for me.